# Different values for ASP.NET Core auth cookie's ExpireTimeSpan and Cookie.MaxAge

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-7.0

ASP.NET Core's cookie middleware can be configured like so:

```cs
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x => {
  x.SlidingExpiration = true;                           // the default
  x.ExpireTimeSpan    = ...
  x.Cookie.MaxAge     = ...
});
```

- `ExpireTimeSpan` sets the lifespan of the actual authentication "ticket" enclosed in the cookie; after that time, the middleware will reject that auth ticket
- `Cookie.MaxAge` sets the lifespan of the cookie itself; after that time the browser should delete the cookie

A scenario: one could configure it such that if the user logs in weekly, the auth ticket would be kept alive for a year (due to sliding expiration); at that point, the cookie itself would reach it's max age and would be deleted by the browser.

Is that the intended use case? Are there other use cases where their values should differ?

Comment: Consider how, in ASP.NET Core, that it's possible to set-up multiple, distinct remote-authentication services (IdPs, such as supporting both Google _and_ Facebook Login for a website). Then consider that a website can then have users are capable of being registered and logging-in by _two or more_ of those IdP simultaneously - so the `AuthenticationTicket` will then contain two or more distinct sets of tokens/session-info/etc for those two IdPs and they'll have differing expiration dates, so the Cookie's expiration would necessarily not match all of the embedded details.

Comment: Granted, if you're doing self-hosted _ASP.NET Core Identity_, or even running your own independent OIDC/OAuth/SAML IdP then, all of your lifetimes and expiration dates will (or at least _should be_) aligned...

Comment: @Dai Thanks that is a use case I didn't consider as I'm using plain Identity without external logins. I can see how it would be useful.